# Special Counters

Tags: c#

I`m trying to create a special counter in C# ... I mean the counter will be consisting of characters not numbers.

I have a `char[]` of size 3:

```
char[] str = new char[strSize];
int i = 0;
int tmpSize = strSize - 1;
int curr;
while(!isEqual(str,finalStr,strSize))
{
    str[strSize] = element[i % element.Length];
    i++;
    if (str[strSize] == element[element.Length - 1])
    {
        int j = strSize - 1;
        if (j > 0)
        {
            j--;
            int tmpCntr = j+1;
            curr = getCurrentID(str[tmpCntr]);
            str[tmpCntr] = element[(curr + 1) % element.Length];
            while (str[tmpCntr] == element[0] && (i % element.Length > 0) && tmpCntr < 0)
            {
                tmpCntr--;
                curr = getCurrentID(str[tmpCntr]);
                str[tmpCntr] = element[(curr + 1) % element.Length];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if the `strSize < 3` the application works fine and gives accurate output. If the `strSize >= 3`, the application goes in infinite loop!

Need help.

if this is hard this way, I would need a way to create a numerical counter and I`ll work on it to suite my application.

Comment: Why not use a numerical counter, then convert it to text when you need to display it? What's in `element`?

Comment: @Tim Robinson: `element` contains the characters that will be used as a counter.

Comment: @Saeed: `getCurrentID()` retrieves the location of the element in `str[*]` in respect to `element[]`

Comment: @Tim Robinson: it will be the same when I use the numerical counter, each location in the array will contain an integer, and the integer can be greater than 9!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't shown what half of your methods or parameters are.

Personally I would take a different approach. I would use an iterator block to make it easy to return an `IEnumerable<string>`, and *internally* just keep an integer counter. Then you just need to write a method to convert a counter value and "alphabet of digits" into a string. Something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Counter(string digits, int digitCount)
{
    long max = (long) Math.Pow(digits.Length, digitCount);
    for (long i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        yield return ConvertToString(i, digits, digitCount);
    }
}
```

Another alternative is to do the same thing with LINQ, if a range of `int` is enough:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Counter(string digits, int digitCount)
{
    int max = (int) Math.Pow(digits.Length, digitCount);
    return Enumerable.Range(0, max)
                     .Select(i => ConvertToString(i, digits, digitCount));
}
```

In either case, you just iterate over the returned sequence to get appropriate counter values.

With those in place, you just need to implement `ConvertToString` - which would probably be something like this:

```
public static string ConvertToString(long value, string digits, int digitCount)
{
    char[] chars = new char[digitCount];
    for (int i = digitCount - 1 ; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        chars[i] = digits[(int)(value % digits.Length)];
        value = value / digits.Length;
    }
    return new string(chars);
}
```

Here's a test program showing it all working:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Show the first 10 values
        foreach (string value in Counter("ABCD", 3).Take(10))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> Counter(string digits, int digitCount)
    {
        long max = (long) Math.Pow(digits.Length, digitCount);
        for (long i = 0; i < max; i++)
        {
            yield return ConvertToString(i, digits, digitCount);
        }
    }

    public static string ConvertToString(long value,
                                         string digits,
                                         int digitCount)
    {
        char[] chars = new char[digitCount];
        for (int i = digitCount - 1 ; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            chars[i] = digits[(int)(value % digits.Length)];
            value = value / digits.Length;
        }
        return new string(chars);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
AAA
AAB
AAC
AAD
ABA
ABB
ABC
ABD
ACA
ACB
```

Comment: @Jon Skeet: what does `.Take(10)` do?

Comment: @sikas: It returns a sequence which only yields the first 10 values from the input sequence. If you haven't looked at LINQ yet, I strongly suggest you do so :)

Comment: OK, I have removed it to display all possibilities and updated some of your code to work with `char[]` instead of `string` and for now it is working

Comment: @sikas: Is there any reason why you need it to use `char[]` instead of `string`? The latter is likely to be easier to cope with in most situations.

Comment: @Jon: I`m using the `char[]` because I have a `char[]` of elements that should be used in the counter. The elements vary from user to user.

Comment: @sikas: Is there any reason why *that* should be a `char[]` rather than a string? Strings are easier to cope with, being immutable etc.

Comment: @Jon: is there any way to convert the `char[]` to string? I don`t mind using `string`

Comment: @sikas: Yes, my original answer used a `char[]` internally and converted it to a string - just call the `string(char[])` constructor.